# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for a word counting program

Tags: python

When I run my current code, I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Specifically, the mostword=wordcount(wordlist) line 62 in the main function, and where I've added for x in wordlist on line 19.  Can you possibly help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

```
def getwords():

#function to get words in the input file
try:
    fp=open("sample.txt",'r')
except IOError:
    print('Unable to open file')
    return
words=[]
#read the file line by line
for line in fp:
    #convert each line into words with space as delimiter
    words=words+line.split()
return words


def wordcount(wordlist):

#function to count words in the file
#worddic is dictionary to store words frequency
worddic=dict()
for x in wordlist:
    #convert word to lowercase to ignorecase
    t=x.lower()
    if(t not in worddic):
        worddic[t]=0
    worddic[t]=worddic[t]+1
max=-1
t=''
for x in worddic:
    if(worddic[x]>max):
        max=worddic[x]
        t=x
return t

def letters(wordlist,lettercount):

#function to count letters in the file
for x in wordlist:
    #For each word in the list
    t=x.lower()
    for y in t:
        #for each letter in the word
        if(not (y in lettercount)):
            #if the letter is not in dictionary add it
            #and set frequency to zero
            lettercount[y]=0
        #increment the frequency of letter in dictionary
        lettercount[y] = lettercount[y]+1

def createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword):

#creates an empty file 'statistics.txt'
try:
    fout=open("statistics.txt",'w+')
except IOError:
    print('Unable to create file')
fout.write('Number of words in the file are '+str(len(wordlist))+'\n')
fout.write('Most repeated word in the file is '+mostword+'\n')
for x in lettercount:
    #write to the file 'statistics.txt'
    fout.write(x+' appeared in the file for '+str(lettercount[x])+'   times \n')

def main():

wordlist=getwords()
#lettercount is a dictionary with letters as keys
#and their frequency in the input file as data
lettercount=dict()
mostword=wordcount(wordlist)
letters(wordlist,lettercount)
createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword)
main()
```

Thanks in advance.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Which one is line 62?

Comment: Paste the whole traceback.

Comment: Perhaps the wordlist is empty in wordcount() method

Comment: print your `wordlist` and have a look at what you are attempting to iterate over, this might help answer the question

Comment: Are you sure your program does not run fine?...I've tested myself, I couldn't replicate your error?

Comment: Try it with a file that doesn't exist and you will see the value of my answer

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming get words is not returning anything within the array because you're appending the lines incorrectly. Add a print words before you return it. When you call get wordcount function, it replies with none type is not iterable.  instead of `words = words.line.split()` , use the append function.  `words.append(line.split())`

Comment: That might append a list to his list. Example: `["a word", "another"].append(["one", "more"])` -> `["a word", "another", ["one", "more"]]`

Answer (score -1):

You declare the `words` inside the function `getwords` *after* the `try/except` block. If the `IOException` is raised, you simply `return`. This would return `None` on a failed `open`. Move `words = []` to before the `try/except`.

This code should work **now**, left `return words` out of exception.

```
def getwords():

#function to get words in the input file
    words = []
    try:
        fp = open("sample.txt", "r")
    except IOError:
        return words
#read the file line by line
    for line in fp:
    #convert each line into words with space as delimiter
        words=words+line.split()
    return words


def wordcount(wordlist):

#function to count words in the file
#worddic is dictionary to store words frequency
    worddic=dict()
    for x in wordlist:
    #convert word to lowercase to ignorecase
        t=x.lower()
        if(t not in worddic):
            worddic[t]=0
        worddic[t]=worddic[t]+1
    max=-1
    t=''
    for x in worddic:
        if(worddic[x]>max):
            max=worddic[x]
            t=x
    return t

def letters(wordlist,lettercount):

#function to count letters in the file
    for x in wordlist:
    #For each word in the list
        t=x.lower()
        for y in t:
        #for each letter in the word
            if(not (y in lettercount)):
            #if the letter is not in dictionary add it
            #and set frequency to zero
                lettercount[y]=0
        #increment the frequency of letter in dictionary
            lettercount[y] = lettercount[y]+1

def createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword):

#creates an empty file 'statistics.txt'
    try:
        fout=open("statistics.txt",'w+')
    except IOError:
        print('Unable to create file')
    fout.write('Number of words in the file are '+str(len(wordlist))+'\n')
    fout.write('Most repeated word in the file is '+mostword+'\n')
    for x in lettercount:
    #write to the file 'statistics.txt'
        fout.write(x+' appeared in the file for '+str(lettercount[x])+'   times \n')

def main():

    wordlist=getwords()
    #lettercount is a dictionary with letters as keys
    #and their frequency in the input file as data
    lettercount=dict()
    mostword=wordcount(wordlist)
    letters(wordlist,lettercount)
    createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword)
main()
```

Comment: This is why people recommend to only use one `return` statement: you would notice errors like this right away.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote..If you think this answer is lacking something feel free to let me know what it is.